# Update stock quantity in database from button click

Tags: c#, sql, database

When I click acceptBTN I'd like to update the Quantity of a certain Item in the stockTBL

```
private void acceptBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string constring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
        string Query = "UPDATE stockTBL SET Quantity = Quantity+ '" + this.quantityTxt.Text + "' where [Item Name] = '" + this.itemTxt.Text + "';";
        SqlCeConnection conDataBase = new SqlCeConnection(constring);
        SqlCeCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCeCommand(Query, conDataBase);

        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Sucess");






            //displays a system error message if a problem is found
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

This is my code, when I click the acceptBTN it just displays the MessageBox without updating the quantity.

Comment: Realised that after I posted it! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't even execute the query you just created it.Try to execute it first

```
conDataBase.Open();
cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();
conDataBase.Close();
```

Some suggestions:

1. Try using [*parameterized queries*](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) instead of *string concatenation* to avoid [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
2. Always use [`using statements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for disposable objects in order to make sure they are properly disposed.

   ```
   string constring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
   string Query = "UPDATE stockTBL SET Quantity = Quantity + @quantity where [Item Name] = @name";
   using(SqlCeConnection conDataBase = new SqlCeConnection(constring))
   using(SqlCeCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCeCommand(Query, conDataBase))
   {
       cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", int.Parse(quantityTxt.Text));
       cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", itemTxt.Text);
       conDataBase.Open();
       cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();
       cmdDataBase.Close();
   }
   ```

Comment: Instead of updating, it just trails off the existing data:
where it previous said (for example) : 5, it now says 56. instead of 11, assuming the quantity ordered was 6.

Comment: @GrantWinney yes it has,  see `SqlCeParameterCollection`methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceparametercollection(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: it isn't different from an ordinary SqlCommand actually, because all of them inherits from the same base class :)

Comment: The code included in the edit works perfectly, thanks @Selman22

Comment: @user3521452 your welcome note that it wasn't work because you were enclosed the _quantityTxt.Text_ with single quotes so the the query was performing the _string concatenation_ instead of _addition_.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery`. You opened the connection but never executed the query.

[MSDN Referece](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).